# Saving D3.js (circles and lines) as an image

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to modify this d3js graph example https://bl.ocks.org/nitaku/7512487 to generate and download as an image. I can get it to work with just the nodes, but can't seem to get the lines (edges) between the nodes to save.

Pasting the following into the console on the example above will generate the image of the nodes:

```
function svg2img(){
    var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
    var svg64 = btoa(xml); //for utf8: btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(xml)))
    var b64start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';
    var image64 = b64start + svg64;
    return image64;
};svg2img()
```

For some wider context, it's used within a Python Flask app - I allow the user to create a graph network, then require it to be downloaded.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you export an SVG to an image like that, you lose all styles that are not inline. After all, it doesn't have access to the CSS files any more, when it's encoded as base64. You are not the first to have encountered this problem, but if you want do do it yourself, you'd need to first traverse the SVG nodes, then get their styles using `window.getComputedLayout(node)`, and then export it. Or you can change the D3 code to apply *all* styles directly onto the nodes using `.attr()` or `.style()`.

If you're fine using outside tools, there are many just on github alone, like [this one](https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng), [this one](https://github.com/domenic/svg2png), and [this one](https://github.com/agordon/d3export_demo). You can install them or just use their code as inspiration.

Comment: Applying the style directly to the nodes and edges worked perfectly, thank you Ruben!

If anyone is looking at this in the future,

```global.vis.selectAll('.link').style("stroke", "red")```